# I got this error simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json, api, weather, forecast

I hope you're doing good.
I'm trying to get the solar radiation values from this website 'solcast.com.au' .. I have went to their API documentation and followed it here ' [https://docs.solcast.com.au/#forecasts-by-location'](https://docs.solcast.com.au/#forecasts-by-location%27) and I have applied the code:

```
import requests
url = 'https://api.solcast.com.au/world_radiation/forecasts?latitude=   -33.865143&longitude=151.209900&api_key=MYAPI'
res = requests.get(url)
data = res.json()
forecast = data["forecasts"]["ghi"]

print('forecastss: {} dgree'.format(forecast))
```

So when I run the code I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/solcastoo.py", line 5, in <module>
    data = res.json()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 897, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 518, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 370, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 400, in raw_decode
    return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Would really appreciate your help.

Comment: `res.json()` is empty.  The documentation says there are several ways to ask that the data be returned in JSON format, and you didn't do any of those.  So the returned data is not in JSON format.

Comment: @John Gordon , So can you please help me with that.. I'm still new to these API stuff.. would really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As John mentioned, you need to specify in your request the format you're willing to receive.
You can do it by adding headers to your request:

```py
import requests
url = 'https://api.solcast.com.au/world_radiation/forecasts?latitude=   -33.865143&longitude=151.209900&api_key=API_KEY'
res = requests.get(url, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
data = res.json()
forecast = data["forecasts"][0]["ghi"]

print('forecastss: {} dgree'.format(forecast))
```

In their documentation they give you two additional options:

1. “Accepts” HTTP request header, eg “​application/json​” for ​JSON
2. “format” query string, eg “​format=json​” for ​JSON
3. Endpoint suffix file extension, eg “​forecasts.json​” for ​JSON

The second option doesn't work, at least for this specific request. The third option works, but it's a bit odd.

The first option is more commonly used in APIs, but be prepared to use other options too.

PS they say in the documentation that `headers={'Accepts': 'application/json'}
should give the desired result, so I'd assume it also could be a possibility in other endpoints.

Good luck